# Prevent dropdown select option on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Check out this link. I would like to disable the dropdown menu. For IE.

http://www.avis.aw/main/reservations/?car=kia_rio&promo=tropicana

I have done this will css but it works with the exception of IE.

```
<div>Pickup</div>
<select name="pickuplocation" id="pickuplocation" class="disabled">
<option selected value="Airport">Airport</option>
<option value="The Mill Resort kiosk">The Mill Resort kiosk</option>
<option value="Costa Linda Beach Resort">Costa Linda Beach Resort</option>
<option value="La Cabana Beach Resort">La Cabana Beach Resort</option>
<option value="Tropicana Beach Resort">Tropicana Beach Resort</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
select.disabled {pointer-events: none; cursor: default;background:#ddd;border: 1px solid #aaa;}
```

But this is not working with this css solution for IE. And I still do want to pass the value. It just needs to be unchangeble to also IE users. Is there a way to make also IE do this?

Regards,

D

Comment: `disabled="disabled"` attribute in the select

Comment: pointer-events:none won't work below IE9

Comment: ok but will it still send the value="value"?

Answer (score 2):

No need for CSS, use `disabled="disabled"`

http://jsfiddle.net/hireconor/h5XD9/